# DateTime Internationalization not working for Norwegian (Nynorsk) locale

Tags: javascript, internationalization, datetime-format

When trying to display the datetime value in Norwegian (Nynorsk) locale, using the javascript internationalization api, I get unexpected results.

I'm using the ISO 639 code for Norwegian (Nynorsk) locale, which is `nn`, but that does not work as expected.

Sample javascript code to print datetime value in the browser console (Google Chrome, language: English)

```js
console.log(
  new Date().toLocaleDateString('nn', { dateStyle: 'full' })
)  
// output: 'Monday, May 9, 2022'
// expected output: 'mandag 9. mai 2022'
```

Any ideas where I'm going wrong?

Am I using the correct locale code? I've tried `nn-NO` as well, but same results. The locale codes `no` and `nb` work, but I can't use them since I guess they map to the Norwegian (Bokmål) locale.

Comment: I'm getting "måndag 9. mai 2022" in FF and Edge when I run your snippet.

Comment: @Teemu I am not in Chrome 100 on win 10 using only 'nn'

Comment: @Teemu It does however https://bugs.chromium.org/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=1215606 - see my answeer

Comment: @Teemu, you're correct. It works in Firefox and Edge, but not in Chrome.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can for now use `nb` - the bokmål date is understood by all Norwegian

the nn(-NO) is a [valid locale](https://metacpan.org/pod/DateTime::Locale::Catalog)  - it seems to [be a Chrome bug](https://bugs.chromium.org/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=1215606)

the code below works in Edge browser but not in Chrome 100

```js
console.log(
  new Date().toLocaleDateString('nb', { dateStyle: 'full' })
)  
// expected and actual output: 'mandag 9. mai 2022'


console.log(
  new Date().toLocaleDateString('nn', { dateStyle: 'full' })
)  
// actual output in Chrome: 'Monday 9. May 2022'
// actual output in Edge: måndag 9. mai 2022

// testing this 
console.log(
  Intl.NumberFormat.supportedLocalesOf(["no", "no-NO", "nb", "nb-NO", "nn", "nn-NO"])
)
// I get [ "no", "no-NO", "nb", "nb-NO" ] in Chrome 100
// and   [ "no", "no-NO", "nb", "nb-NO", "nn", "nn-NO" ] in Edge
```

Comment: I understand that in terms of date format, both Nynorsk and Bokmål maybe same, but why isn't the Nynorsk locale supported? Couldn't find anything on the web to regarding this.

Comment: Bug: https://bugs.chromium.org/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=1215606